# Empty items being added to array of refs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```js
const nodeRefs = useRef<Array<HTMLDivElement | null>>([]);

function setNodeRefs(ref: HTMLDivElement | null, idx: number): void { nodeRefs.current[idx] = ref; }

{nodes.length === 5 && nodes.map((node, idx) => (idx === 1 || idx === 2)
    && (
        <MyComponent
            setNodeRefs={setNodeRefs}
            idx={idx}
            key={String(`${idx}-${uuidv4()}`)}
            className="h__node"
        />
    ))}
```

However the resulting array of refs includes an empty item:

> [empty, div.h__node, div.h__node]

It seems like a node is being set in the array of refs even when the condition inside the map is not met.

How can I create the array without adding the empty item to it?

Comment: I guess you meant `ref={setNodeRefs}`, right? Also, passing `idx={idx}`can't really work... `HTMLElement` doesn't have a `idx` property. Could you correct the code? Also, what is nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting the elements at indices `1` and `2` respectively, and the `0`th index of your `nodeRefs.current` array is `undefined`.

Depending on your requirement, subtracting `1` from `idx` or using `Array#push` should do.

Answer (score 0):

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on **every element** in the calling array.

Hence even though you have conditions, the size of the array will remain unchanged when you use `.map`. You may want to use .forEach or for-loops.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map